# Find all users in a roomID

Tags: sql

Consider I have the following table:

```
+----+--------+--------+
| id | roomID | userID |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |      9 |     34 |
|  2 |      9 |     76 |
|  3 |     87 |     90 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

I want to find the roomID where only certain users are participating in - so in this instance I want to find the roomID that *only* users 34 and 76 are using.  How can I do this?

Comment: is it not possible with IN Clouse?

Comment: No attempt made to solve the problem

Comment: Add a few more of sample data, and also the expected result. What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Few of the answers that the guys are replied, are almost similar. So voted up that answer is think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> find the roomID that **only** users 34 and 76 are using

```
SELECT 
    roomID
FROM 
    TABLE1
WHERE     
    roomID IN (SELECT roomID FROM TABLE1 WHERE userID = 76) 
    AND 
    roomID IN (SELECT roomID FROM TABLE1 WHERE userID = 34)
    AND
    roomID NOT IN (SELECT roomID FROM TABLE1 WHERE userID NOT IN (34, 76))
```

Comment: `NOT IN` is a bit tricky when null values are involved. I usually recommend to always use `NOT EXISTS` instead, do avoid surprising result.

Comment: Thank you, the subquery actually makes sure that there are no other uses in the same roomID, something which every other answer overlooked.

Comment: except this issue mentioned above, i would say that this should be accepted as a right answer. Of course only if sub-queries are acceptable.

Comment: @Chud37 what happened if another user is added to the list with userID = 88 and roomID = 9. It will return nothing where Record Count:0. See the execution [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/af242/1)

Comment: @khayyam Sorry I thought this worked but it doesnt.  Because the IN statement is shorthand for OR, if another there was another row with the same room ID, and I searched for `34,76` in my IN clause it still returns the roomID 9.  I want *only* those results.

Comment: @Chud37 You are right. I have modified the query. Now should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you're asking something different, aren't you?
This is how you can find the `roomID` of users `34` and `76`:

```
select
  roomID
from
  table
where
  userID in (34,76)
```

Comment: Lol no - It turns out I have never had the need to use the IN statement before so I didnt know about it :)

Comment: But what if there is another user in roomID 9? It will still return roomID 9.

Answer (score 1):

you can use below query:

```
select roomID from your_table_name where Userid in (34,76)
```

for unique data you can use:

```
select roomID from your_table_name where Userid in (34,76) group by roomID
```

Comment: grouping by for uniqueness is a bit of over engineering i would say. better to use distinct https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: Thank you.  It turns out I didnt know about the IN statement until today!

Comment: But what if there is another user in roomID 9? It will still return roomID 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: **IN**

```
SELECT roomID FROM table_name WHERE userID IN (34, 76);
```

Comment: But what if there is another user in roomID 9? It will still return roomID 9.

Comment: yes... it doesn't matter if there are any other users in this room... you are searching those specific users ID's so you will get their room id that they are in.