# get multiple rows from table where column = array

Tags: mysql

This is a revised question of my previous question, because I dont think I asked it correctly.

I am creating a chat room in NodeJS, and in order to do that I have the following table that lists which users are in each room:

```
+----+--------+--------+--+
| id | roomID | userID |  |
+----+--------+--------+--+
|  1 |      9 |      3 |  |
|  2 |      9 |   4786 |  |
|  3 |      9 |   7991 |  |
|  4 |      7 |      3 |  |
|  5 |      7 |   4786 |  |
|  6 |      1 |      3 |  |
+----+--------+--------+--+
```

I need to be able to select from the list the roomID from an array of users.  So lets say, I want to get the roomID that users `4786` and `3` are using, It would return 7.  If I wanted to get the roomID that users `4786`,`3` AND `7991` are using, it would return 9.

Okay so.  In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47429395/find-all-users-in-a-roomid) the answer I got was to use `SELECT * FROM table WHERE userID IN (4786,3,7991)`.  What I didnt realise (I dont use the IN statement that much) was that the IN statement was essentially a shortcut for the `OR` statement.

Which leads me to the problem, The first thing I tried was `OR` and because it doesnt explicitly match each userID in the table, the results are unreliable.

[I've created an SQLFiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da6285/3)

I want to be able to say: Give me the unique roomID for these users and and **these users only**.  It doesnt matter if they are involved in other rooms.

I hope i've made myself a bit more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da6285/6)**

```
SELECT roomId, COUNT(CASE WHEN `userID` IN (4786,3) 
                          THEN 1
                     END) total_match
FROM `chat-room-users` 
GROUP BY roomId
HAVING total_match = 2  -- because are 2 users in (4786,3) 
   AND total_match = COUNT(`userID`)
```

Lets say you put your users in a table `search_user` to be more generic your query become:

```
SELECT roomId, COUNT(CASE WHEN `userID` IN (SELECT userID FROM search_users) 
                          THEN 1
                     END) total_match
FROM `chat-room-users` 
GROUP BY roomId
HAVING total_match = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM search_users) 
   AND total_match = COUNT(`userID`)
```

Comment: Can you explain what is going on here? Specifically the `COUNT(CASE` bit?  It does seem to work though!

Comment: Is a conditional `COUNT()`, basically count how many user are in that roomId group with that characteristic. you can add `THEN 1 ELSE NULL`  but for `CASE` expression that is the deffault and `COUNT()` doesnt count `NULLs` Finally you check if the `total_match` is equal to the total of user on that room to make sure everyone and only them are there.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I wouldnt have been able to figure that out for myself :)